# jquery ajax submit button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got a register form using bootstrap modal that will call an ajax post function.

however, it does not seems to execute my $.post.
Also, how do i use the return value from my php function into my ajax data? so if my createAccount returns true or some other value, how does my ajax capture it?

```
<form action="" id="registerForm" method="POST">
   .....
        <div class="d-grid gap-2"> 
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnRegister" type="submit">Register!</button>

</form>
```

my ajax.

```
$("#email").keyup(function(){
    var email = $("#email").val()
    {
        $('#emailResult').remove();
        $.post("createaccount.php",{
            checkEmail : email
        }, function(data){
            if(data=="true")
            {
                error=true;
                var str = '<div id="emailResult">';
                str +='<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">';
                str +='Email address already exists!';
                str+= '</div></div>';
                $('#result').append(str); 
            }
            else
            {
                error="false";
            }
        });
    }
});

    $("#btnRegister").click(function(){
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("password").val();
    $.post("createaccount.php",{
        email : email,
        password : password
    },function(data){
        alert(data);
    })
});
```

my createaccount.php

```
<?php
include("db.php");
include("functions.php");

if(isset($_POST['checkEmail']))
{
    $email = $_POST['checkEmail'];
    {
        if(checkEmailExists($email))
        {
            echo "true";
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(createAccount($email,$password))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
?>
```

my functions.php

```
function createAccount($email,$password)
{
    global $conn;
    $hashPassword = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = "INSERT into USERS (email,password) VALUES ('$email','$hashPassword')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        echo mysqli_error($conn);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, is there any error message at all on the development console?  Use the script debugger (or, failing that, strategically use `console.log` statements to provide useful debugging output in your code) to see if the button click handler is being invoked at all.  Are you trying to bind the handler to the button before the button exists on the page?

Comment: You neglected to suppress the default action of the event, so this form submits _normally_, and cancels any running JS operations you might have when it does so.

Comment: @CBroe can you explain with example??

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: @RiggsFolly i am trying out the functionality first. thereafter, will do the necessary security

Comment: @RiggsFolly please see my edited ajax code. i have another .keyup function that called the checkEmail

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
$("#btnRegister").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   // Your code...
```

Instead of

```
$("#btnRegister").click(function(){
   // Your code...
```

This code will stop form from submitting on button click.

Btw for email checking use another true false value to prevent form submitting until mail validation result comes.

```
var error=true;
$("#email").keyup(function(){
    var email = $("#email").val()
    {
        $('#emailResult').remove();
        $.post("createaccount.php",{
            checkEmail : email
        }, function(data){
            if(data=="true")
            {
                error=true;
                var str = '<div id="emailResult">';
                str +='<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">';
                str +='Email address already exists!';
                str+= '</div></div>';
                $('#result').append(str); 
            }
            else
            {
                error=false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And later...

```
if(!error){
    $.post("createaccount.php",{
        email : email,
        password : password
    },function(data){
        alert(data);
    }) 
}
```

Comment: once i added the preventDefault(), my default form validation does not work. i am using this <input id="email" type="email"

Comment: Try using jquery validation plugin. https://jqueryvalidation.org/. It will make your life very easy

Answer (score 0):

In order to get to the correct place in your PHP code you need to have a `submit` parameter in the POST array

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

But your AJAX call does not pass that parameter so add it

```
$("#btnRegister").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $.post("createaccount.php",{
                                email :     $("#email").val(),
                                password :  $("password").val(), 
                                submit: 1               // New line
                                },
        function(data){
            alert(data);
    })
});
```

You could also use a `e.preventDefault();` to stop the browser submitting the form in the normal way as well as doing your AJAX call